# Why am I not getting floating point numbers?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am writing a very simple practice script (I am a novice) that will take in values of a, b, c, and x and plug them in to a quadratic function.

For some reason I am not getting floating point numbers into my equation.  I have tried adding float() to more places than I feel I need to, and yet I'm still getting fixed point numbers.

Note: I ended up with this many float inputs after trying several ways; this is merely the last iteration.  Here is my code:

```
def quadratic(a, b, c, x):

    return float(a*x**2 + b*x + c)

print "Let's find the output value for the values in a quatratic function..."
print "Our formula is ax^2 + bx + c = ?"

a = float(raw_input("What value for 'a'?"))

b = float(raw_input("What value for 'b'?"))

c = float(raw_input("What value for 'c'?"))

x = float(raw_input("What value for 'x'?"))

solution = float(quadratic(a, b, c, x))

print "(%d)(%d)^2 + (%d)(%d) + %d = %d" % (a, x, b, x, c, solution)
```

and here is my output (after entering decimal values for a, b, c, x).

```
Let's find the output value for the values in a quatratic function...

Our formula is ax^2 + bx + c = ?

What value for 'a'?.75

What value for 'b'?.44

What value for 'c'?.3467

What value for 'x'?.77

(0)(0)^2 + (0)(0) + 0 = 1
```

Clearly this is user error on my part.  Can someone provide insight as to why I'm getting fixed point numbers?  Thanks!

Comment: Use `%s` instead of `%d`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you so much, that was such an easy fix and it worked right away.  So I take this to mean that %d only returns integers?

Comment: %d means digit. %f means float, %s means string

Comment: @Hanzy `%s` or `%d` *do not return*. Instead they control how thing are printed (formatting). `%d` prints integer numbers.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  I found an answer on another post that suggested %d meant decimal but I must have misunderstood.  You all helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several other users commented, the issue is not with your calculation, but with the formatting of your output string. The `%d` formatting sequence tells Python to convert the relevant value to an integer before turning it into a string. Using a different code would make it work the way you expect.

The most obvious code to use would be `%f`, which indicates that you want a float value. You can add some extra characters if you want the float to round to a particular number of decimal places (rather than the default which may be very long). Using `%.4f` for instance would round at four decimal places, which might be a good choice since that's the maximum number of significant digits you used in your example inputs.

Another option would be to use `%s`, which means you want to convert the argument directly to a string using the builtin `str` function. This doesn't allow the nicer rounding options of `%f`, but it will work for almost any type (even non-numeric ones).

I'd actually go further and recommend that you use an alternative formatting method entirely. The `str.format` method allows you to do some more sophisticated formatting than the `%` operator does, which is a useful in this situation since you want to repeat the same `x` value twice. Using an appropriate format string with `str.format` lets you duplicate the value in the output without needing to repeat it in the arguments. Here's one way of doing it using keyword arguments to `str.format`:

```
print "({a:.4f})({x:.4f})^2 + ({b:.4f})({x:.4f}) + {c:.4f} = {solution:.4f}".format(
    a=a, b=b, c=c, solution=solution, x=x
)
```

If you were using Python 3.6+ (which I'd also recommend for a wide variety of other reasons), you could use what are known as ["F-strings"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to do the same formatting as the call above, but without needing to explicitly call `format` and pass in a bunch of variables as keyword arguments with their own names. When you prefix the first quotation mark with an `f`, Python will do the formatting for you based on the variables in your current namespace:

```
print(f"({a:.4f})({x:.4f})^2 + ({b:.4f})({x:.4f}) + {c:.4f} = {solution:.4f}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. This is more helpful than I could have even asked. I'm beginning my novice python work in "Learn Python the Hard Way" like many others who have asked n00b questions like mine. It seems like that guide is geared toward Python 2.7 but overall I've found the exercises quite easy and I'm able to extend them to simple scripts of my own. My next task will be to learn Python 3.6+, but I'm not sure what a good resource would be to bring me up to speed. I'll be done with this book soon.